# How to make ffmpeg segment filename have the time created

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` to segment a video stream and I would like `ffmpeg` to name the segment files with a created date/timestamp.

Is this possible?

Let's say I have segments of 30sec video each: `0000.flv`, `0001.flv`, `0002.flv`, etc

When I do `ffprobe` of each video segment I "correctly" get 30 seconds, which is nice.

*However*, each file has a "last modified time"/"created time" that I can read, and when I subtract `0001.flv` (modified time) - `0000.flv` (modified time) I get a result of 29 seconds.

The video duration is 30 seconds, but the time between either date created or last modified is 29 seconds!

If the segment time is 600 seconds then the time between either date created or last modified is 591 seconds! So it's missing 9 seconds according to the file system but the video is indeed 600 seconds.

This is a huge problem -- can someone please help?

This is my commandline:

```
    ffmpeg = spawn('ffmpeg', [
        '-loglevel', 'quiet',
        '-r', '20',
        '-i', 'pipe:0',
        '-vcodec', 'copy',
        '-f', 'segment',
        '-segment_time', '30',
        dataDir + '/' + '%04d.flv'
    ]);
```

Also, when ffmpeg writes the segment the files have no "birth time" and the "created" & "modified" time is always the same.. so i really can never know when the file was actually created unless i use a "debugfs" (in sudo mode) to dig deeper....

all i want is ffmpeg to put a timestamp in the filename when it creates the segment, why is this not seen as useful? i think its very useful when capturing time from a live source...

and i am NOT encoding-- stop thinking that this is encoding please... i know that transcoding take longer and cause delays in time...

From my observation, doing a codec copy, the "last modified" time between segments is only 591 seconds when i have my video duration at 600 seconds... so i am actually losing time...

But i know this is not a reliable timestamp-- so i am asking for a way to get a more reliable timestamp from ffmpeg other than having to use the "stat" command which is not giving me reliable timestamps...

And yes-- my camera is producing at 20 fps :)

Comment: Why should the file creation time be exactly the same as the duration? And why is this a requirement? Normally, encoding time would be longer than duration. Also, please provide your input command and uncut console output.

Comment: I am in agreement, why do you expect encoding time to match duration of video?

Comment: Think of it this way, each segment "represents" a place in time. If i look at a file segment, how can i place it in a timeline? The segment need to provide me a reference point in time. The segment is 600 seconds long, how else can you map each segment to a period in time?

Comment: I am segmenting a live camera stream to hard disk for playback later-- think of a video surveillance system-- you need to play back what happened x minutes ago.. etc.. each segment must correctly map into a place in time.. now i am ok with margin of error of lets say 1-2 seconds, but when my segment is 600 seconds long i get an error (by looking at file create/modify timestamps) of 9 seconds-- this is way too much missing time.. i know the video is capturing the time correctly cause the duration is correct but i am not able to map it into a timeline cause i do not have correct timestamps.

Comment: Also, i am not encoding here-- just a codec copy..

Comment: Im using the ffmpeg on a mac, i've noticed that on the linux ffmpeg i needed to put "-map 0" in my commandline parameters to make it work.... but the command works as shown above on my mac just fine.

Comment: " If i look at a file segment, how can i place it in a timeline?" Well you could just put them one after another if the files are serially named. I'm not sure I fully understand your requirement or what the problem is. It is pretty trivial to arrange them.

Comment: If you are looking to "access" video at a real (clock) time, one way is to burn in TC and/or write timecode while recording. Your camera(s) should have that facility or a TC input where you can feed an external "house" TC from a TC generator.

Comment: Thanks for the input guyz, you got me thinking about a different approach--- i will simply use ffmpeg to write a "chunk of 100mb buffer" of video to disk.. and i will get timstamps when the buffer is created and when the buffer is full to know what time period that chunk represents.. so i will spawn an ffmpeg to concurrently write one buffer to disk while another fills up. -- and i will name each chunk with a begin time and end time :)